# Motorola 68k word storing

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, motorola, easy68k

Can someone explain why FF00 is stored in d1 after:

```
MOVE.W  #$FFFF, d1
ADD.B   #1, d1
```

I understand that a word is 16 bits in 68k architecture but was wondering why the result is FF00 rather than 00FF and what would change if `MOVE.B` or `MOVE.L` were used?

Comment: That should load `0000FFFF`, and it does on my version of easy68k.

Comment: What has you expecting that it would be `$000000FF`, and how did you get to the value `$0000FF00`?

Comment: FYI, after a `move.w #$FFFF, d1`, we would expect `d1.w` to hold `FFFF`.  We cannot say what `d1.l` (aka `d1`) will hold since `d1.l` is the full 32-bit register and that `move.w` only affects the lower 16 bits of `d1`, aka `d1.w`.  The upper 16 bits of `d1` will remain as they were before the `move.w` and we don't know that that is.

Comment: Sorry I am new to 68k and now know that it would not be 00FF, I also missed out ADD.B #1, d1 after MOVE.W #$FFFF,d1 but was not sure if the second instruction would make a difference since the result is not stored but I am most likely mistaken

Comment: Yes that is important, because the `add.b` is a byte sized operation, so adding to `d1.b`, which is the lower 8 bits of `d1`.  So, what's being added by that instruction is FF and 1.  Together, those make 0 (or 00). and so the lower 8 bits of `d1` will hold 00.  The 16 bits of `d1.w` will hold FF00, then because the FF part is unaffected by the `add.b`, and thus carries over from the prior value (set by the `move.w`).

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your answer and time, that now makes much more sense

Comment: Suggest to update your question to include the `add.b`, it might have more value for us that way.

Comment: Yea sorry sure thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `move.w` instruction places FFFF into `d1.w`, which is the lower 16 bits of 32-bit `d1`.  The upper 16 bits are unaffected by this move, so without more information we can't say what's in `d1` (`d1.l`), but we know that we have XXXXFFFF in `d1` (where the x's represent unknown).

Because the `add.b` is a byte sized operation, it is adding to `d1.b`, which is the lower 8 bits of `d1`.  What's being added by that instruction is FF and 01.  Mathematically that addition result is 0x100, however, as this is an 8-bit addition instruction, the result is truncated to 0x00 (condition codes are set if the program wants to know about overflow signed or unsigned).  Added together and truncated to 8 bits, we get 00, and so the lower 8 bits of `d1` (aka `d1.b`) will hold 00.  The 16 bits of `d1.w` will hold FF00, then because the FF part is unaffected by the `add.b`, and thus that part carries over from the prior value (set by the `move.w`).

The 32-bit register `d1` will hold XXXXFF00, where the XXXX is unknown as it comes from some code sequence prior and not shown.

---

If `move.b` were used we then could not speak to the upper 24 bits of the `d1` register, since they would be unaffected by the code sequence.  The result would be xxxxxx00 in register `d1`, where x means don't know.

If `move.l` were used we would know positively the full value of the `d1` register: 0000FFFF would be the initial value after the move, and 0000FF00 the final value after the `add.b`.